# Set breakpoint at overloaded function which name includes space in WinDBG

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

Now I debug a program by using WinDBG. This program call 'operator new' function.

With symbols, This function call can be accessed by the symbol name, *"MSVCR90!operator new".*

But this function name have space(' ') and overloaded by two types. *MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int)* & *MSVCR90!operator new* *(unsigned int, int, char *, int)*

Therefore, I cannot set breakpoint on this function easilly. I typed below methods, but allthing I typed was failed.

```
0:008> bp @!"MSVCR90!operator new"
Matched: 74b00939          MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int, int, char *, int)
Matched: 74af3e99          MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int)
Ambiguous symbol error at '@!"MSVCR90!operator new"'
          ^ Extra character error in 'bp @!"MSVCR90!operator new"'

0:008> bp @!"MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int)"
Couldn't resolve error at '@!"MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int)"'
          ^ Extra character error in 'bp @!"MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int)"'
```

I finally set breakpoint at 'operator new', but I used offset for it.

Is there anyway to 'MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int)' ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a symbol name, WinDbg will lookup that symbol and use the associated address. In your above output, it shows two matches and their addresses: 74b00939 and 74af3e99. So just choose the appropriate address given. Lets say that you want MSVCR90!operator new (unsigned int), just use `bp 74af3e99`.

Regarding symbol resolution, you can also use the x command. For example:

```
x MSVCR90!operator*new
```

This will output the same list of matches along with their addresses.

Comment: "just use bp 74af3e99" - IMHO that's what the OP already did since he said "I used offset for it"